# error: could not convert ‘total’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::string’

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a currency converter from pln to either usd or euros. However I keep getting the error

> could not convert ‘total’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::string’

How do you suggest I fix it and what did I write wrong in the code below?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int converting(string convertcurrency, int pln, int total)
{
    if (convertcurrency=="dollars")
        total = pln * 0.22;
    else
        total = pln * 0.25;
    return total;
}

int main()
{
  cout<<"Welcome to my currency converter program! There are currently two choices of currency to convert to from PLN: euros (€) and us dollars ($). \n\n";
  int pln;
  int total;
  string convertcurrency;
  cout<<"Please input the amount of PLN you'd like to convert. ";
  cin >> pln;
  cout<<"Which currency would you like to convert " << pln << "PLN to? (euros/dollars) ";
  cin >> convertcurrency;
  /*cout << Euc_ver2(a, b);
  return 0;*/
  cout << "Converting " << pln << "PLN to " << convertcurrency << ". . . \n";
  cout << converting(total) << convertcurrency;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `converting` function *expects three arguments*, why are you *supplying only one?* Before writing any real c++ program, I would recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: And why are you mixing floating points with integer calculations? You might want to watch this : [floating point numbers (computerphile)[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0]. With currencies is often helps to keep track of fractions as integers themselves

Comment: A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Also look at functions like [std::stoi/std::stod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) on how to convert strings to numbers. And learn to pass strings by (const) reference to avoid unecessary copying e.g. `int converting(const std::string& convertcurrency, int pln, int total)`

Comment: The correct call, given the existing code, is `converting(convertcurrenty, pln, total)`. But `total` should be a local variable in `converting`, not an argument. With that change, `converting` would take two arguments: `converting(convertcurrency, pln)`.

Comment: Your function `converting` has been written with three parameters (but it should only have two). However you are calling it with only one argument. When you call a function, the number of arguments and the number of parameters must match, and also the type of each argument individually must match as well. This is basic stuff about functions, you should probably revise that material in your C++ book.

Comment: I don't like that this is closed. The problem is reproducable, and it's not caused by a typo, it's caused a lack of understanding about how functions work. Such a question deserves an answer.

Comment: ^ or a reasonable duplicate. At any rate, it's open now. Go to town, @john

Comment: Don't show us *"a currency converter"*. Show us *"could not convert ‘total’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::string’"*. Take out what isn't needed (especially the I/O) to reproduce this error so readers don't have to hunt through your code for the problematic line. Should be half a dozen lines at most. See [mre].

Comment: The full error message should contain more information, including the exact location of the error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few misunderstandings about functions here. The first is in `converting` where `total` should not be a parameter. `total` is the value you are **returning** from the function, parameters are generally for values you are passing into the function. Here's `converting` rewritten with `total` changed from a parameter to a local variable

```
int converting(string convertcurrency, int pln)
{
    int total; // local variable
    if (convertcurrency=="dollars")
        total = pln * 0.22;
    else
        total = pln * 0.25;
    return total;
}
```

The second error concerns how you call a function. When you call a function you must use the same number of *arguments* with the same types as the number of *parameters* that the function has. Originally your `converting` function had three parameters, but now I have rewritten it, it only has two. However your code only supplied one parameter

```
cout << converting(total) << convertcurrency;
```

Also looking that the function, the first parameter should be a string (the currency to convert to) and the second parameter should be the amount of currency to convert. Here's how the code should look

```
cout << converting(convertcurrency, pln) << '\n';
```

You can also remove the variable `total` from `main` it's only needed in the `converting` function, not in `main`.

Pretty simple, but a lot of beginners do get confused about functions, what parameters are for, what return values are for, when to use local variables etc. etc.

Comment: thank you john for the timely help! i'm now looking back at my code and seeing the errors i have made, which are now fixed. guess i will have to study more about functions and parameters :)